# What is the expected value of the number of factors of a number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, expected-value, factoring

I recently learnt that the expected number of prime factors for an integer $n$ is on the order of $\log\log n$. This was apparently proven by Hardy and Ramanujan.

This led to me wondering what the expected number of (total) factors for a given number is.

I am aware that, if $n=p_1^{\nu_1}p_2^{\nu_2}p_3^{\nu_3}\cdots p_k^{\nu_k}$, then the number of factors of $n$ is $\prod_{i=1}^k\left(\nu_i+1\right)$. I also know that $\displaystyle P(\nu_i=a)=\frac1{p_i^{~a}}$. 
Not sure how to proceed, though.

Comment: Are you asking about the divisor function? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the divisor function.

Comment: You have $\prod \nu_i+1$.  I believe that should be $\prod \mathbf(\nu_i+1\mathbf)$.

Comment: Right! I didn't realise that the notation was slightly ambiguous. Also thanks for fixing a few errors I made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to look at the problem upside down. Instead of looking at each integer and wondering how many divisors they have, which can get quite hard, you instead count how many integers in $[1,n]$ have $k$ as a factor, for $1 \leq k \leq n$. As there are about $n/k$ such integers, you can estimate this by

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \#\{j \leq n : k|j\}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{n}{k}+O(1))=(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k})+O(1)=\log(n)+O(1),$$

using the estimation $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}=\log(n)+O(1).$$

Comment: I should mention that the result you are talking about can be proved similarly, but instead of summing over all integers less than $n$, you sum over all primes less than $n$. You are then left to estimate $\sum_{p \leq n} 1/p$, which is about $\log\log(n)$ by Mertens' second theorem.

Comment: That's a nice answer, and presumably we can more rigorously show the number of divisors is $\log n$ because $n\log n-(n-1)\log(n-1)=\log n+(n-1)\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)=\log n+1+O\left(\frac 1n\right)$. I wonder, is it possible to specify what $O(1)$ equals though?

Comment: We have more precisely that $\#\{j \leq n : k|j\}=n/k-\{n/k\}$, where $\{n/k\}$ denotes the fractional part of $n/k$. Also, $H_n=\log(n)+\gamma+O(1/n)$, where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant. So a more precise estimate would be that the average is $(\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \{n/k\})+\log(n)+\gamma+O(1/n)$.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks!